# How to display placeholder text as option in React Select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I am using React Select Package for dropdown. I wanted the placeholder option to display in the menu option for the user to select it as the dropdown field is not mandatory and the user can leave them empty or unselected.

I have tried many ways. I created a Custom placeholder component to display, but that is also not working. I tried passing a hardcoded value in options array. But that would also not work as i will be getting options from api afterwards.
I have posted my code in Sandbox for better clarity.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-bush-3wstx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You question is not clear to me. You want placeholder text to be your menu option. Then this field may or may not be selected? An I right ? Could you share an image of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Is there any problem with `isClearable` prop of `React-select`, change it to `true` and I think it serve your need.

Comment: @MarsonMao Yes i tried that disabled prop, But it is not selectable. Does not serve the purpose actually. The Text needs to be selectable.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Yes correct bro, It needs to be selectable.

Comment: I mean how should it be different from other options. If directly provided in Options ? That's what I want to know :)

Comment: Then remove that `isDisabled` and I think you need to tweak some `innerProps`

Comment: [+One] also needs to know what Imran asked

Comment: @MarsonMao Yes the placeholder text needs to be in the menu option. The field may or may not be selected. I tried with your example, But the placeholder value from menu option is not getting selected.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather No difference, just that the value can be selected and deselected.

Comment: Then simply put that in the options object and keep the same placeholder name as well using placeholder prop :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather If possible, can you please show it in the sandbox ?

Comment: I mean something like this ... https://codesandbox.io/s/we-are-here-we-are-here-kdg50